# confluent Kafka consumer stuck after broker restarts

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am using  kafka_image=wurstmeister/kafka

zookeeper_version=3.4.14
    kafka_version=2.12-2.4.0

C# client: Confluent kafka v1.2.0

We are
    using 3 brokers , 1 zookeeper cluster As a pat deployment we use to
    stop all the brokers ,zookeeper,producer,consumers and delete the
    kafka-log files, and starts consumers first later will starts the
    brokers and zookeeper. In this process some time consumer getting
    stuck, its not picking any messages even it alive. If  i restarts
    the consumer, it started picking

Comment: Thanks for answer,
i didn't found any ERROR in logs,

Comment: Not clear why you would start consumers before any server is available to process the request

Answer (score 2):

Rebalance can be the reason for such a behaviour. When rebalance starts in a consumer group, all the consumers in this group are **revoked** and during rebalance consumers cannot commit offset or poll data until rebalance finishes and partitions are assigned to new consumers.

---

Some important notes to consider:

- rebalance timeout is equal to `max.poll.interval.ms`. So if your max.poll.inteval.ms is so high because of long running processes then rebalance can take so much time.

  **Reasons to rebalance:**
- Joining new consumer to consumer group
- Clean shutdown of a consumer
- Adding new partition(s) to a topic which is subscribed by the consumer group
- When a consumer is considered dead by the group coordinator

  - Expiring `session.timeout.ms` without sending heartbeat
  - Not calling poll during `max.poll.interval.ms`

Reason to face with rebalance after restart can be the **joinGroupRequests** that consumers send to group coordinator by calling poll. Each requests trigger to rebalance. (in potentially) Then you are getting lots of rebalances. To overcome this problem, you can increase `group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms`. It is 3 sec in default.

> **group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms**: The amount of time the group
>   coordinator will wait for more consumers to join a new group before
>   performing the first rebalance. A longer delay means potentially fewer
>   rebalances, but increases the time until processing begins.

Comment: Thanks for comment,
yes i understood it some how related to rebalance,
re balance will be done by kafka broker right,once i starts my broker it should balance all consumers coz already my consumers are up and ruining.

Comment: am new to this kafka zone, can u please explain a bit more

Comment: Is there any pattern like first up brokers and then up the consumers ? or we can up anything dynamically

Comment: @Rafi actually each consumer which sends joinGroupRequests (poll) triggers rebalance. So you have probably more than rebalance at the start of the Kafka brokers. You can check broker logs. During rebalance you would see logs like that *Preparing to rebalance group*. I don't know any pattern like this, but you can use group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms to delay rebalance and wait all consumers to send joinGroupRequests so there would be fewer (possible just one) rebalance.

Comment: I found below logs from server.log

INFO [KafkaApi-93] Auto creation of topic local_test with 1 partitions and replication factor 1 is successful (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
INFO [GroupCoordinator 93]: Preparing to rebalance group local_test in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 0 (__consumer_offsets-9) (reason: Adding new member rdkafka-006e28cc-f71e-48c1-8b66-b20c3c640d5d with group instanceid None) ()
INFO [GroupCoordinator 93]: Stabilized group local_test generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-9)

Comment: I have 3 consumer group, each will have only one consumer, so the moment i clear all  kafka-logs and start the brokers up may the re balance will trigger, since i have only one consumer in my consumer group so it should starts picking instead of idle. But am not sure why its happening with only one consumer where  remaining consumers are working as expected, and this behavior random not regulr.

Comment: @Rafi rebalance can take long time (rebalance timeout is equal to max.poll.interval.ms) When rebalance starts Kafka waits all alive consumers in the consumer group to call poll. If one of your consume process is takes so much time then this can be the reason of long rebalance times. You should check process time of consumers and max.poll.interval.ms.

Comment: I gave group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms gave 1min, but today i again consumer got stucks. is there any other solution?

Comment: @Rafi is this happened after broker restart? If it is not, I suggest you to ask another question and explain the situation clearly by sharing configs and logs. If it is happened after broker restart then I guess I have nothing more to say other than the answer I provided :)